# Search Bar Doesn't Appear When View loads - iOS

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm having a problem when one of my views initiated. I'm trying to get the search bar to show up when the view is initiated, but it shows up when I start scrolling down. 
This shows up when I click on it:
[image]

and I'm trying to get this to show up when the view is initiated, which currently only shows up only when I start scrolling:

[image]

This is the code I have to set the search controller up so far:

```
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Posts", "Users"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.isHidden = false
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
//        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
//        navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
```

I've tried lots of different ways to get the search bar to appear when clicked on but I haven't been successful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line:

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

And if you wan't to show if from the beginning and hide it when scrolling then you need to do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
}
```